# Dynamic values in a Lex custom slot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I'm trying to create an intent for my app with a custom slot for a 'category' in Amazon Lex. Is there a way to hook-up the slot values to a GET request that fetches the categories from my database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give few samples for the slot values in the Lex console, then after the user enter some category you can validate in the backend using GET requests by matching.